# Method overloading conflicting with transaction object

Tags: transactions, web3js

In my contract there is a `buy` method with 1 argument being overloaded by a 2nd one with 2 arguments:

```
function buy( uint id )
function buy( uint id, uint quantity )
```

Now I want to call the 1st method via web3, but also provide the options for the underlying `sendTransaction`, to specify the `from`, `value` and `gas` values.

How can I call this and prevent the 2nd `buy` method with 2 arguments to be called as happens currently with:

```
myContract.buy(id, { gas: 100000 })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Fabian Vogelsteller indicated on Gitter](https://gitter.im/ethereum/web3.js?at=571621033ddb73ba105d6641) that we also have the signature as a method name available. Which is documented in [EIP68](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/68), and looks like this:

```
myContract.transact({from: …}).myMethod(param1)
// or
myContract.call({from:...})['5fd434dd'](param1)
```

So specifically for my question, the solution was using:

```
myContract.buy['uint256'].buy(id, opts)
```

Comment: Note that the above is in the making and not yet possible in the current web3.js

Comment: @FabianVogelsteller has this been added to web3?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is too obvious, and I am not trying to be flippant, but why not change the interface? buyQuantity for the second function.

Answer (score 0):

In web3 v1 it is documented [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)

> myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]])

Creates a transaction object for that method, which then can be called, send, estimated.

The methods of this smart contract are available through:

- The name: `myContract.methods.myMethod(123)`
- The name with parameters: `myContract.methods['myMethod(uint256)'](123)`
- The signature: `myContract.methods['0x58cf5f10'](123)`

This allows calling functions with same name but different parameters from the JavaScript contract object.